# Problems with Streamwriter

Tags: c#

I know it sounds really stupid, but I have a really easy application that saves some data from some users on a database, and then I want to write all the data on a .txt file.

The code is as follows:

```
    List<MIEMBRO> listaMiembros = bd.MIEMBRO.ToList<MIEMBRO>();


    fic.WriteLine("PARTICIPACIONES GRATUITAS MIEMBROS: ");
    mi = new Miembro();
    foreach (MIEMBRO_GRATIS m in listaMiembroGratis)
    {
         mi.setNomMiembro(m.nomMiembro);
         mi.setNumRifa(m.numRifa.ToString());
         fic.WriteLine(mi.ToString());
    }
    fic.WriteLine();
```

As you see, really easy code. The thing is: I show the information on a datagrid and I know there are lots of more members, but it stops writing in some point.

Is there any number of lines or characters to write on the streamwriter?? Why I can't write all the members, only part of them???

Comment: Have you wrapped this in a try/catch to see if any Exception is being thrown?

Comment: How is your StreamWriter declared?  Are you flushing it, closing it properly?

Comment: if you are not sure about what @Romanarmy means by flushing set AutoFlush property to True, and make sure that you are Disposing of the StreamWriter fic properly would need to see full code to make sure you are using the implementation of the StreamWriter properly as well.. I would also suggest anything with a StreamWriter, that you wrap in a Try Catch, also create or declare the instance as null first outside of a using(){} then when creating the new as long as it's within a using(){} it will be disposed automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fic` is probably not being flushed by the time you are looking at the output file; if you instantiate it as the argument for a `using` block, it will be flushed, closed, and disposed of when you are done.

Also, in case you are flushing properly (but it is not being flushed by the time you are checking the file), you could flush at the end of each iteration:

```
foreach (MIEMBRO_GRATIS m in listaMiembroGratis)
{
     mi.setNomMiembro(m.nomMiembro);
     mi.setNumRifa(m.numRifa.ToString());
     fic.WriteLine(mi.ToString());
     fic.Flush();
}
```

This will decrease performance slightly, but it will at least give you an opportunity to see which record is failing to write (if, indeed, an exception is being thrown).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any number of lines or characters to write on the
>   streamwriter??

No, there isn't.

> As you see, really easy code. The thing is: I show the information on
>   a datagrid and I know there are lots of more members, but it stops
>   writing in some point

My guess is that your code is throwing an exception and you aren't catching it. I would look at the implementation of  `setNomMiembro, setNumRifa` and `ToString` in `Miembro`; which, by the way, in the case of `setNomMiembro` and `setNumRifa` should probably be implemented as properties (`{get;set;}`) and not as methods.

For example, calling `ToString` in `numRifa` would throw a null pointer exception if `numRifa` is null.

Comment: I also had a try catch, but I didn't copy it... No exception thrown!